# React Native map function to get date drom database

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to display the date form my database (firestore) on my frontend but it only gives me seconds and nanoseconds as values when it clearly correct in the database.

I am doing a map function to get the data from the database.

```
<Text style={styles.datecon}>{comp.date.seconds}</Text>
```

The above code works but gives me a string of all the seconds.

```
<Text style={styles.datecon}>{comp.date}</Text>
```

The above code doesn't work due to it being an object and needs to be expanded but I can onlyu expand it to seconds and nanoseconds.

[image: Console.log]

Here is where I console.log the data

[image: Firestore]

Here is the data in firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer (from bgcodes) I mahnage to fix the error and also fixing the date to not say 1970 you should just *1000 to get the correct date

```
const convertToDate = (seconds) => {
    return new Date(seconds*1000).toString();
}
```

```
<Text style={styles.datecon}>{convertToDate(comp.date.seconds)}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to convert seconds to date.

```
const convertToDate = (seconds) => {
    return new Date(seconds).toString();
}
```

Then use it in your jsx.

```
<Text style={styles.datecon}>{convertToDate(comp.date.seconds)}</Text>
```

Comment: Okay it translates thge seconds to date but the date is completly wrong, it says Mon Jan 1970 13:54:11 when its in the db  22 Auguist 2022 1:15

Comment: In that case, my guess is you are using the wrong date from firestore. Can you console.log the entire object?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, thank you the problem was you should just multiply the seconds with 1000

Comment: Ah, I suppose it takes milliseconds rather than seconds. Good u figured out.

Answer (score 0):

What you get from the SDK is a Firestore-specific type called a `Timestamp`, which has helpful methods listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp).

One of these is to get a `Date` object from the timestamp, which you'd do with , much simpler with:

```
<Text style={styles.datecon}>{comp.date.toDate()}</Text>
```